# MySQL Resultset Issue

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have an array of author names, I have to select a number of authors articles there is limitation that author name is in the content which is text. is there any good solution that i don't have to fetch the record one by one can i get record of each author in a single query.

```
SELECT n0_.id AS id0 
  FROM newspaper n0_ 
       INNER JOIN newspaper_translation n1_ ON n0_.id = n1_.translatable_id
       INNER JOIN newspaper_channels n3_ ON n0_.id = n3_.news_id 
       INNER JOIN channels c2_ ON c2_.id = n3_.channel_id 
 WHERE n1_.locale = 'zh_CN' 
   AND (c2_.reference_id = '057PL' AND n1_.content LIKE '%黎子珍%') 
 ORDER BY n0_.id DESC 
 LIMIT 1
```

I want to pass pass multiple author names and want to get single record of the each author. But I want to execute query once.

Answer (score 0):

You can construct the `where` clause using a sequence of `or` statements:

```
WHERE n1_.locale = 'zh_CN' AND c2_.reference_id = '057PL' AND
      (n1_.content LIKE '%黎子珍%' OR n1_.content LIKE '%子珍%' OR n1_.content LIKE '%黎子%')
```

However, if you have any control over the database, you should have a table that matches authors to each item, with one row per author and item the author has worked on.  This is called a junction table and it makes it much easier to answer these types of questions.

EDIT:

You can take your original query and repeat it using `union all`:

```
(SELECT n0_.id AS id0 
  FROM newspaper n0_ 
       INNER JOIN newspaper_translation n1_ ON n0_.id = n1_.translatable_id
       INNER JOIN newspaper_channels n3_ ON n0_.id = n3_.news_id 
       INNER JOIN channels c2_ ON c2_.id = n3_.channel_id 
 WHERE n1_.locale = 'zh_CN' 
   AND (c2_.reference_id = '057PL' AND n1_.content LIKE '%黎子珍%') 
 ORDER BY n0_.id DESC 
 LIMIT 1 )
UNION ALL
(SELECT n0_.id AS id0 
  FROM newspaper n0_ 
       INNER JOIN newspaper_translation n1_ ON n0_.id = n1_.translatable_id
       INNER JOIN newspaper_channels n3_ ON n0_.id = n3_.news_id 
       INNER JOIN channels c2_ ON c2_.id = n3_.channel_id 
 WHERE n1_.locale = 'zh_CN' 
   AND (c2_.reference_id = '057PL' AND n1_.content LIKE '%黎珍%') 
 ORDER BY n0_.id DESC 
 LIMIT 1 )
```

However, at this point, you might as well just run separate queries.

Comment: The problem is I don't have any authors association.

Comment: But I need exactly one for each like it will be returning a lot of records.